# Write the output to a file

Tags: python

I'm creating a simple program that creates serials

For the code I use

```
import random
import string

charList = ["A", "B", "C"]
g560List = ["LX38200", "LX38201", "LX38202"]

whatSerial = input("Choose a serial to generate").upper()

def g560(g560List, charList):
    return g560List + charList + "8" + " -> G560")
if whatSerial == "G560":
    for i in g560List:
        for i2 in charList:
            print(g560(i, i2))
```

now this works fine. The program printed all the possible serials out the console, however I want to change it so it saves it to a file (e.x: it creates a file called "output.txt" and then all the outputs are saved there).

How'd I implement that?

Answer (score 2):

You can print to a file relatively easily, with:

```
with open('output.txt', 'w') as outFile:
    print('something', file=outFile)
    print('something else', file=outFile)
```

Just make sure, for efficiency, you're opening the file once then printing everything within the `with` (probably between the `if` and the first `for`).

Answer (score 1):

You could simply use your shell to redirect standard output:

```
python myprog.py > output.txt
```

If you want to do it all in Python then something like the following should serve:

```
with open('output.txt', 'w') as f:
    if whatSerial == "G560":
        for i in g560List:
            for i2 in charList:
                print(g560(i, i2), file=f)
```

Comment: Just FYI, the default mode for `open` is read, you'll need to specify a different mode if you want to write to it. The output redirection is actually a reasonably good idea if you want all output with minimal (i.e., no) code changes.

Comment: Fixed, thanks. Redirection _is_ rather more flexible than using a hard-coded file name.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to redirect output from stdout to a file, you can also do it in the following way:

```
from contextlib import redirect_stdout

with open('output.txt', 'w') as f:
    with redirect_stdout(f):
        print('it now prints to "output.text"')
```

But if you're new to python and want simplicity, just follow paxdiablo's answer.

Reference: [`contextlib.redirect_stdout`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.redirect_stdout)

---

**Edit:** no one posted the most basic solution - writing to a file:

```
with open('output.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write('stuff to be saved to the file')
```